# Tensorflow) Why variables are not assigned after restoration?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-serving

I'm learning tensorflow and doing an experiment using pre-trained weights of alexnet.

I saved after 13000 iterations and i am trying to re-train the model after restoration.

But after restoration, the weight is not changed with the value used in initialization.

Why is this happend? All the code (even, tensorflow official site) just introduces the code to restore:

```
saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
```

But this code doesn't have any effect on the variables.

The result picture is below :
[image]

As you see, after restoration, the weight called 'conv2/kernel' executed by 'session.run('conv/kernel:0') is different from the one from 'model-+13000.ckpt'

I think many people would be struggling with this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you restore your model from a checkpoint, you don't want to use `tf.global_variables_initializer()` anymore. (You just do it the very first time you create the model to initialize weights before training begins, otherwise you are basically starting over from scratch again.)

This should work better:

```
saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
print sess.run('conv/kernel:0')
```